# Sublime Text 2 - Read a file located on a different server (http://host.com/my-text-file.txt)

Tags: sublime-text-2

As the title says, is it possible to open up a file as I can do in chrome (http://host.com/my-text-file.txt). Bonus points if you can make it auto refresh and scroll to the selected line.

Comment: You may want to try Nettuts+ Fetch plugin

Comment: @T-- I saw fetch before, but it is unfortunately for a different purpose. P.S. Nettuts is a tutorial site, and thus not part of the plugin :)